# I do need help in writing SQL Query in ORACLE for the below sample data

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

My data looks like below:

table

```
REF_NUM ID  DATE
SIM1    1   12-Oct-22
SIM1    2   10-Oct-22
SIM2    3   15-Oct-22
SIM2    4   14-Oct-22
SIM3    5   08-Oct-22
SIM3    6   02-Oct-22
SIM4    7   08-Oct-22
SIM4    8   10-Oct-22
```

Output should be as below:

Output:

```
REF_NUM ID  DATE
SIM1    2   10-Oct-22
SIM2    4   14-Oct-22
SIM3    6   02-Oct-22
SIM4    7   08-Oct-22
```

basically I need data with distinct ref_num , respective ID and with SECOND HIGHEST DATE. Here I have just given two dates in main table, But each ref_num can have more than two dates.

I can sure that whatever I have tried is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Rank rows per each `ref_num` by the date datatype value in descending order; then fetch these that rank as the second highest.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (ref_num, id, datum) as
  2    (select 'sim1', 1, date '2022-10-12' from dual union all
  3     select 'sim1', 2, date '2022-10-10' from dual union all
  4     select 'sim2', 3, date '2022-10-15' from dual union all
  5     select 'sim2', 4, date '2022-10-14' from dual union all
  6     select 'sim3', 5, date '2022-10-08' from dual union all
  7     select 'sim3', 6, date '2022-10-02' from dual union all
  8     select 'sim4', 7, date '2022-10-08' from dual union all
  9     select 'sim4', 8, date '2022-10-10' from dual
 10    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 11  temp as
 12    (select ref_num, id, datum,
 13       rank() over (partition by ref_num order by datum desc) rnk
 14     from test
 15    )
 16  select ref_num, id, datum
 17  from temp
 18  where rnk = 2
 19  order by ref_num;

REF_         ID DATUM
---- ---------- ----------
sim1          2 10.10.2022
sim2          4 14.10.2022
sim3          6 02.10.2022
sim4          7 08.10.2022

SQL>
```

Comment: You want `DENSE_RANK` as it will get the second highest if there are multiple records tied for highest. If you use `RANK` then there would be no second highest as it would immediately jump from 1st to 3rd.